# Caching Lambda Docker images from a CDK stack in a pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

For simplicity, suppose we have a stack that contains a single lambda function created as a Docker image:

```
import { Stack, StackProps, Duration } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

export class FunStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const exampleFun = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "ExampleFun", {
      code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("lambda/example_fun"),
      timeout: Duration.seconds(10)
    });
  }
}
```

I'm omitting the contents of `lambda/example_fun` because it is straightforward, i.e., it contains a single .py file with some dummy handler and a Dockerfile that uses say public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 as base and uses the handler as cmd.

Now, especially if there were many such lambdas and/or they were large, a CDK pipeline such as the one you construct as part of the [AWS CDK Workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript.html) won't cache any of them. Concretely, let us have:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as codecommit from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codecommit';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import {CodeBuildStep, CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource} from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
import { FunStack } from "./fun-stack";
import { Stage, StageProps  } from "aws-cdk-lib";

export class FunPipelineStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new FunStack(this, 'Fun');
    }
}

export class FunPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const repo = new codecommit.Repository(this, 'FunRepo', {
            repositoryName: "FunRepo"
        });

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            pipelineName: 'FunLambdaPipeline',
            synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep', {
                input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, 'master'),
                installCommands: [
                    'npm install -g aws-cdk'
                ],
                commands: [
                    'npm ci',
                    'npm run build',
                    'npx cdk synth'
                ]
            })
        });

        const deploy = new FunPipelineStage(this, 'Deploy');
        const deployStage = pipeline.addStage(deploy);
    }
}
```

How should the pipeline be modified to allow us to cache the `DockerImageFunction` the pipeline generates when deploying?

If I'm reading correctly the documentation for [Build caching in AWS CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-caching.html) and deducing correctly from the [CDK docs for BuildSpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.html), I think I should use `codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject` to specify the buildspec file.

With some experimentation, I'm able to do simple install and/or build commands via `fromObject` and the buildspec file, but can't quite figure out how to cache. In particular, how can the pipeline refer to the Docker image being built as part of the stack? The goal is that on each build, in case the Docker images haven't changed, they would be read from the cache and avoid being rebuilt.

Perhaps another alternative is to set up an ECR repository, somehow on each build check whether the hash of the built container is found and if not, build and push. However, I don't know how to concretely do this as I can't see how to refer to the Docker images built, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a partial buildspec with the [`partialBuildSpec`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html#partialbuildspec) prop and specify the caching method using the [`cache`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html#cache) prop as shown in the [module overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#customizing-codebuild-projects):

```
    ...
    synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, 'master'),
        installCommands: [
            'npm install -g aws-cdk'
        ],
        commands: [
            'npm ci',
            'npm run build',
            'npx cdk synth'
        ],
        partialBuildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
          cache: {
            paths: [ "path/to/cache/**/*" ]
          }
        }),
        cache: codebuild.Cache.bucket(new s3.Bucket(this, 'Cache')),
    })
```

Other than that, your premise is faulty: the containers will be built in any case - you can just make it faster. It's impossible to know whether the container hash changed without building it first. If you want to cache docker layers to make builds faster, you can try including `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/**/*` in the cache.

Possibly relevant:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19157

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9080